# HTML - Making td resizable when containing an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. I have a anchor tag within a DIV. I want to align anchor text on top.
2. That div is within one row of table. This table will have 4 rows. I want table to resize to its content - i.e. if two rows are present , then table should decrease its size.

I am not sure about what all css should is et to achieve this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you eliminate the use of tables all together. Would be easier to help if you include some code.